# Rendering ANSI codes in git-bash console inside Vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, git-bash

I have scoured the internet for a solution to this issue that is driving me crazy, but so far no luck.

I have git bash on Windows 10, and when I run any Python script that outputs colored text on it, everything works fine as long as I'm running it **outside** of Vscode. However, when I open bash as an integrated terminal in Vscode, the sequences are not recognized.

I have found a few answer in SO about this, but they all state that this is a problem with windows terminals, but this is absolutely not true. Not only because when running it outside of vscode it works, but also because when I run the same code with cmd or PS as the integrated terminal, the colors render just fine.

See screenshot that illustrates it: https://ibb.co/5jFyNFS

Why is git bash behaving differently from anything else inside Vscode? Is there anything I can do about it?

Here's the sample code for reproducing the issue:

```
def esc(code):
    return f'\033[{code}m'

print('this is ', esc('31'), 'really', esc(0), ' important', sep='')
```